# Trying to reconnect a socket.io socket that was explicitly disconnected

Tags: node.js, tcp, websocket, protocols, socket.io

After calling `socket.disconnect()` on the client side, I try to reconnect that client `io.connect("http://localhost:8000")` but the socket does not seem to be created. Is this possible to do without a page refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a socket created with something like

```
var connection = io.connect();
```

in your client-side JS, you can reconnect via

```
connection.socket.connect();
```

Comment: sweet, thanks! How did you figure this out? By reading the source?

Comment: I actually ran into this issue myself recently, and I had that code handy. :) I found the method by toying with the `connection` object in the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

A typical use case would be

```
var socket;
var firstconnect = true;

function connect() {
  if(firstconnect) {
    socket = io.connect();
    ... do something else

    firstconnect = false;
  }
  else {
    socket.socket.reconnect();
  }
```